# Use widescreen for embedded YouTube videos

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, layout

For embedded YouTube videos, can the player be 16:9 instead of 4:3? Most video game videos will be in this aspect ratio nowadays. And it takes no additional screen real-estate: if you just make the video player as wide as the answer area, and leave the height the same, you'll have a 16:9 player. And 4:3 video will just have black columns on the sides. ([Example of an answer with embedded YouTube video.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/47445/137))

---

### How it is today

[image: Example of 16:9 YouTube video embedded in 4:3 player.]

---

### How it could be

[image: Example of 16:9 YouTube video embedded in 16:9 player.]

---

<sub>Note: I requested this some time ago [over on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93184/use-widescreen-format-for-embedded-youtube-links) and it got heavily downvoted (9 downvotes in a very short time). I still don't understand why anyone wouldn't want this, so I'm asking here in the hopes that we can at least get this on the Gaming site.</sub>

<sub>If anyone is interested, I wrote [a GreaseMonkey script to do this that's over on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2427/use-widescreen-format-for-youtube-videos-embedded-in-stack-exchange-pages).</sub>

Comment: I think this should be system-wide, myself.  I've offered a bounty on your MSO post.

Comment: @MatthewRead the tide may have turned, i now have way more upvotes than downvotes on the MSO post. my best guess is that people didn't know you tube links were already converted to players on some sites, and they thought my originalpost was *requesting* a feature to convert youtube links. otherwise i don't know why it received all downvotes initially. i think adding the mockup has helped a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to have been completed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123438/141361

Comment: Confirmed - I just edited the post referenced in the question and it converted to 16:9